# Need help creating Sumif/match index or vlookup formula for a template using multiple criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I'm trying to create a formula in Column `S` that sums up items in Column `R` based using the following logic.

Value in column `S3` = If the value in Column `L3 = "14000"` then find and sum up the values in Column `R4:R1000` for rows where column `K4:K1000 = M3` and column `L4:L1000 = 30120, 30121, 30140, or 30141`.

The idea behind this is trying to find offset accounts. Anything with a `14000` account is offset by `30120, 30121,30140 and 30142` accounts. The key that the accounts are related is `K` and `M`.

I know this is confusing, so if you need clarification, please let me know.

[image]

Comment: You might want to tag this with Excel or OpenOffice or LibreOffice depending on what spreadsheet software you're using. Otherwise you're unlikely to get attention from people who might know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good usecase for `SUMPRODUCT()`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($L$3=14000)*($K$4:$K$1000=$M$3)*($L$4:$L$1000={30120,30121,30140,30141})*($R$4:$R$10000))
```

`SUMPRODUCT()` will test for each condition across a range of columns or rows. In this case it's rows 4:1000 for `K` and `L` and their respective conditions. It also is testing `L3` to be equal to `14000`. It then gathers up the sums where those conditions are true in the Range `R4:R1000`.

One caveat when using Sumproduct is that the ranges that you are testing have to be the exact same size (unless it's just a single cell like it is here with `L3`). So adjust accordingly.